# Pulling data from a file to use as a payload

Tags: scapy

How can I have Scapy pull a file and send it within an ICMP packet?

I am using Scapy to create an ICMP packet and want it to pull a file and include it in the payload.  I have been messing with the basic send command and cant figure out the next step.

send(IP(dst="1.1.1.1")/ICMP()/{file.txt}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to read the file into a string (or bytes) with open and read, then add it as Raw.

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    s = f.read()
send(IP(dst = '1.1.1.1') / ICMP() / Raw(load = s)) # you can, also, omit Raw(load = s) and just add it as ... / string_variable
```

Depending on the file length and content type slight modifications may be needed. This example works with a small text file.

Answer tested with scapy3k (http://github.com/phaethon/scapy) and python3, but it should work with scapy, too.